# Website Scraping Using PHP

Tags: php, html, xpath, web-scraping, domdocument

I have a php code that could extract the product categories in this website: http://www.tradeindia.com/. So far I had managed to extract only the categories. How do I make it so that it will also extract the product numbers beside it since its not in any class name?

My code:

```
<?php 
//header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 
$grep = new DoMDocument(); 
@$grep->loadHTMLFile("http://www.tradeindia.com/"); 
$finder = new DomXPath($grep); 
$class = "cate_menu"; 
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$class')]"); 

$total_L = 0; 
foreach ($nodes as $node) { 
$span = $node->childNodes; 
echo '<br>' . $span->item(0)->nodeValue . ' : '; 
} 

?>
```

Source code from website:

```
<td align="left" style="padding-left:8px;color:blue"><a href=/Seller/Agriculture/ class="cate_menu" >Agriculture</a>(100892)</td>
<td align="left" style="padding-left:8px;color:blue"><a href=/Seller/Apparel-Fashion/ class="cate_menu" >Apparel & Fashion</a>(237902)</td>
<td align="left" style="padding-left:8px;color:blue"><a href=/Seller/Automobile/ class="cate_menu" >Automobile</a>(78614)</td>
```

I need the numbers between brackets.

Comment: regex will do the job quite well in this case.

Comment: if its possible I want to do it using this way(domdocument)

Comment: hello cael, which products are you scraping anyway? featured products?

Comment: The number of products in the categories on the top. I've got the categories list(Agriculture, Apparel & Fashion) but I cant get the number beside it(minus the brackets).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an xpath guru, but what I would do is to target first that particular table using that needle categories, then from there get those rows based on that and start looping on found rows.

Rough example:

```
$grep = new DOMDocument();
@$grep->loadHTMLFile("http://www.tradeindia.com/");
$finder = new DOMXpath($grep);

$products = array();
$nodes = $finder->query("
    //td[@class='showroom1'][contains(text(), 'CATEGORIES')]
    /parent::tr/parent::table/parent::td/parent::tr
    /following-sibling::tr
    /td[1]/table/tr/td/table/tr
");

if($nodes->length > 0) {
    foreach($nodes as $tr) {
        if($finder->evaluate('count(./td/a)', $tr) > 0) {
            foreach($finder->query('./td/a[@class="cate_menu"]', $tr) as $row) {
                $text = $row->nodeValue;
                $number = $finder->query('./following-sibling::text()', $row)->item(0)->nodeValue;
                $products[] = "$text $number";
            }

        }
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($products);
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/PmX2Pe)

Comment: thanks, i've tried it but it seems like it can only extract the first column. Is there a way to get the rest 2 columns?

Comment: @Cael check my revision again, its now corrrect

Answer (score 1):

Since the number is between two brackets, this should be easy. You can use a function like this;

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end) {
    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = strpos($string,$start);
    if ($ini == 0) return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);   
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}

$product = get_string_between($htmlline, "(", ")");
```

You will need to get each line of the table inserted separately though. You could loop through an array of strings containing each line; `foreach($htmllines as $htmlline)` or similar.

Hope this helps.