# Scrape a decoded information with PHP & Curl

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, scrape, scraper

I'm trying to understand how to scrape decoded phone numbers from a yellow page website with PHP & Curl.

Here is an example URL:
https://www.gelbeseiten.de/test

Normally you can technically do it with something like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$page = curl_exec($ch);

if(preg_match('#example html code (.*) example html code#', $page, $match))
    $result = $match[1];
    echo $result;
```

But on the page mentioned above you cannot directly find the phone number in the HTML code. There must be a way to get the phone number.

Can you please help me out?

Best regards,

Jennifer

Comment: It might be far easier to use `DOMDocument` and `XPath` - the element cntaining the phone number is handily assigned a class ( `phone` ) so you could access them directly rather than trying to use regular expressions

Comment: @RamRaider the phone number is somehow encoded then appended into the HTML DOM, i think that what the OP asking about, so it is not about use regex or DOMDocument... etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Website Scraping Using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26397335/website-scraping-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

[Don't use regex to parse html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), use an html parser like [DOMDocument](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), i.e.:

```
$html = file_get_contents("https://www.gelbeseiten.de/test");
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->query('//span[contains(@class,"nummer")]') as $item) {
    print trim($item->textContent);
}
```

Output:

```
(0211) 4 08 05(0211) 4 08 05(0211) 4 08 05(0211) 4 08 05(0231) 9 79 76(0231)...
```

Comment: Thank you, but this script doesn't get the last two digits of the number.

Comment: This website has a protection that only shows the last part of phone number if javascript enabled, which is not the case with php. You may want to use www.seleniumhq.org/.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in a comment - using an XPath expression yields the phone numbers as desired.

```
$url='https://www.gelbeseiten.de/test';

$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile( $url );
$xp=new DOMXpath( $dom );

$query='//li[@class="phone"]';
$col=$xp->query($query);

if( $col ){
    foreach( $col as $node )echo $node->nodeValue . "<br />";
}
$dom = $xp = $col = null;
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately this script doesn't get the last two digits of the number. Do you have an idea, how to solve this?